# How can I set customized separators for theorem counters?

Tags: counters

How can I set customized separators for theorem counters? For example in

[image]

The chapter, section and number are separated with **dot**. How can I change these dots to other symbols? For instance how can I change the first dot with dash and the second dot with comma?

This is a code extracted from [this site](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Theorems_and_proofs) which produced the picture above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined

\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ is 
a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
\label{pythagorean}
This is a theorema about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
equation 
\[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
\end{theorem}

And a consequence of theorem \ref{pythagorean} is the statement in the next 
corollary.

\begin{corollary}
There's no right rectangle whose sides measure 3cm, 4cm, and 6cm.
\end{corollary}

You can reference theorems such as \ref{pythagorean} when a label is assigned.

\begin{lemma}
Given two line segments whose lengths are $a$ and $b$ respectively there is a 
real number $r$ such that $b=ra$.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: an example code added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the representation of the counters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection--\arabic{theorem}}

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\renewcommand{\thecorollary}{\thetheorem, \arabic{corollary}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined

\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ is 
a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
\label{pythagorean}
This is a theorema about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
equation 
\[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
\end{theorem}

And a consequence of theorem \ref{pythagorean} is the statement in the next 
corollary.

\begin{corollary}
There's no right rectangle whose sides measure \SI{3}{cm}, \SI{4}{cm}, and \SI{6}{cm}.
\end{corollary}

You can reference theorems such as \ref{pythagorean} when a label is assigned.

\begin{lemma}
Given two line segments whose lengths are $a$ and $b$ respectively there is a 
real number $r$ such that $b=ra$.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the code you put does the produce your output.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Oh, sorry! Pasted wrong version! Fixing in a moment.